# Emit does not work inside axios call, but does outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I want to emit data to a parent component after a succesful axios call, but for some reason emit does not work when resolving the promise. Emit works fine when putting it before or after the axios call.

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I'm using arrow functions so `this` shouldn't be changed, and even then - I tried doing it with functions and assigning `this` to a variable before going into the axios call but that didn't work either.

I made a custom config for axios, but changing it back to the default does not change anything either.

```js
// ApiWrapper.js
// this is the custom axios config I'm using

import axios from 'axios';

const apiWrapper = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'my_url',
})

apiWrapper.interceptors.request.use(function(config) {
    let hasToken = localStorage['token'] || false;

    if(hasToken) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    }

    return config
}, function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
})

export default apiWrapper;
```

My App, which is the parent and listens to the `token` event.

```js
<script>
// App.vue

import { generalState } from './helpers/GeneralState';
import Loading from './components/generic/Loading.vue';
import LoginPage from './views/LoginPage.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Loading,
      LoginPage
    },
    data() {
      return {
        token: null,
        generalState: generalState
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setToken(token) {
        console.log('in setToken');
        console.log(token);
        this.token = token;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  
  <div class="flex h-screen bg-sgray">
    <div class="m-auto">

      <section class="h-full gradient-form md:h-screen">
        <div class="container py-12 px-6 h-full">
            <div class="flex justify-center items-center flex-wrap h-full g-6 text-gray-800">
                <div class="block bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg">
                  <template v-if="generalState.isLoading">
                    <Loading/>
                  </template>
                  <template v-else-if="!token">
                    <LoginPage @token="setToken" />
                  </template>
                  <template v-else>
                    <router-view/>
                  </template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And finally, my LoginPage which should emit the returned `token` to the parent component.

```js
// LoginPage.vue

<script>
import Input from '../components/generic/Input.vue';
import Button from '../components/generic/Button.vue';
import apiWrapper from '../helpers/ApiWrapper';
import { generalState } from '../helpers/GeneralState';

export default {
    components: {
        Input,
        Button
    },
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        process_form(e) {
            generalState.isLoading = true;
            let token = null;

            this.$emit('token', 'TOKEN-BEFORE');

            apiWrapper.post('login/', {
                email: this.form.username,
                password: this.form.password
            }).then(resp => {
                token = resp.data.token;
                this.$emit('token', token);
            }).finally(() => {
                generalState.isLoading = false;
            });

            this.$emit('token', 'TOKEN-AFTER');
        }
    },
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="lg:flex lg:flex-wrap g-0">
        <div class="lg:w-6/12 px-4 md:px-0">
            <div class="md:p-12 md:mx-6">
                <h4 class="text-xl font-semibold mt-1 mb-12 pb-1">Sign in</h4>
                <form v-on:submit.prevent="process_form">
                    <p class="mb-4">Manage all your integrations.</p>
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <Input v-model="form.username" inputType="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <Input v-model="form.password" inputType="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center pt-1 mb-12 pb-1">
                            <Button buttonType="secondary" role="submit">
                                Log in
                            </Button>
                        <a class="text-gray-500 hover:underline" href="#!">Forgot password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center pb-6">
                        <p class="mb-3 mr-2">Don't have an account?</p>
                        <Button buttonType="primary" role="button">
                            Sign up
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lg:w-6/12 flex items-center lg:rounded-r-lg rounded-b-lg lg:rounded-bl-none bg-sred">
            <div class="text-white px-4 py-6 md:p-12 md:mx-6">
                <h4 class="text-xl font-semibold mb-6">One platform for all integrations.</h4>
                <p class="text-sm">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is the part that is not working:

```js
methods: {
        process_form(e) {
            generalState.isLoading = true;
            let token = null;

            this.$emit('token', 'TOKEN-BEFORE'); // <-- This emit DOES work

            apiWrapper.post('login/', {
                email: this.form.username,
                password: this.form.password
            }).then(resp => {
                token = resp.data.token;
                this.$emit('token', token); // <-- This emit DOES NOT work
            }).finally(() => {
                generalState.isLoading = false;
            });

            this.$emit('token', 'TOKEN-AFTER'); // <-- This emit DOES work
        }
    },
```

I'm pulling my hair out because I cannot see why the emit inside the axios is not working.
Can anybody help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, that the `then` part is called at all? Maybe there is an error happening inside the post request.

Comment: Hi @LeifMarcus, I can confirm that the `then` is called. I can log the received token and other data, before or after the emit, but the emit itself seems to do nothing.

Comment: Well check if your setToken method is called

Comment: @Lk77 The setToken method does not get called when emitting inside the axios call, but does get called when emitting outside the axios call.

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans try to remove your emits before and after the post request, when you are emitting, your component get destroyed, since there is a `v-else-if="!token"`

Comment: @Lk77 Those emits are purely to illustrate that they do work, and the one inside the axios does not. Removing the emits does not change the outcome.

Comment: It's your `generalState.isLoading = true` that causing the issue, replace the `v-else-if` by a `v-if`, so your component does not get removed. You could also to use a v-show to hide it but not remove it.

Comment: @Lk77 Thank you, that was indeed the problem! Feel free to leave it as an answer so I can mark it as answered. Could you also elaborate why the generalState is causing the issue? I don't quite see it.

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans glad i can help, i made a more detailled answer

Comment: Seeing the accepted answer this issue was solved, but I see another issue in the code. I recommend to not use `this` in lambdas as it usually points to the `window` object and not the object you are thinking it would point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LoginPage component is displayed using a v-else-if :

```
<!--  when generalState.isLoading is true -->
<template v-if="generalState.isLoading">
    <Loading/>
</template>
<!--  that component get removed, 
which means the token event listener get also removed -->
<template v-else-if="!token">
    <LoginPage @token="setToken"/>
</template>
```

What you can do is :

1 / don't use v-else-if, but a simple v-if instead, so your component is not removed

2 / Use a v-show to hide your component without removing it, because you might encounter styling issues, it's cleaner to hide it so your loader is displaying fine.

```
<!--  when generalState.isLoading is true -->
<template v-if="generalState.isLoading">
    <Loading/>
</template>
<!--  that component do not get removed but just hidden -->
<template v-if="!token" v-show="!generalState.isLoading">
    <LoginPage @token="setToken"/>
</template>
```

What is happening is that your axios callback get actually called, but your component has been removed by then and is going to be destroyed, so the parent component no longer listen to the events that the component is emitting